# Is it safe to download an HTML file on an unknown website using something like Python's urllib.urlretrieve?

Tags: malware, javascript, python

I know that some sites can infect you with malware just from visiting them. Is this because they run JavaScript in your browser? So would merely downloading the HTML and not running its JavaScript be safe? Are there other attack vectors to worry about?

Comment: what you describe is safe. content has to be interpreted as code to be dangerous, comparing strings is just that, comparing strings; doesn't matter what the strings contain (with very few and temp exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

If a site uses a JavaScript-based exploit, then not executing the JavaScript code will indeed mitigate that exploit.

Note that (1) not all browser attacks are JavaScript-based, for example pure HTML or CSS could also be used, and (2) any code or library you use can have other vulnerabilities, though the odds of them being prepared for such a random library being used are very slim, so it's almost certainly fine.

Comment: Thanks! Do HTML and CSS attacks require parsing/rendering the page to some degree? My intended application at the moment is to merely diff the raw text of two HTML files.

Comment: @BrianTomasik Such vulnerabilities are almost always in the parsing. It could also be in the headers, but I rarely heard of those in response headers. A raw diff should generally be perfectly safe for anything but state-level malware. And I'd argue that even state-level malware won't do much unless they predicted you will be using urllib and/or some specific diffing library.